# Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n = M$ be a convergent series with $a_n \ge 0 \in \mathbb R$. Non-contradiction proof: $s_k \le M$ for $k \in \mathbb N$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n = M$ be a convergent series with $a_n \ge 0 \in \mathbb R$.

I want to prove $s_k \le M$ for $k \in \mathbb N$.

I could do a proof by contradiction as follows:

Suppose $s_N > M$ for $N \in \mathbb N$. Since $a_n \ge 0$ we have $s_k \ge S_N$ for $k \ge N \in \mathbb N$.

Let $s_N = L$ and $\alpha = L - M > 0$.

Let $\epsilon < \alpha$ then $|s_k - M| \ge \alpha$ for $k \ge N \in \mathbb N$,  a contradiction that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\{s_k\} = M$.

Is there another way of proving this result not using an argument based on contradiction.

Comment: $$M-s_k = \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty a_n \geqslant 0\,?$$

Comment: $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n = M \Rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n - s_k = M -  s_k \ge 0 \ \ \ \forall k \in \mathbb N$$. Thank you, I should have thought of this.

Comment: Daniel, how could I show that for a positive continuous function $f(s)$ where $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} F(x) = \int^x_a f(s) ds = M$ we have $F(x) \le M \ \ \forall x \ge a \in \mathbb R^+$?

Comment: If we know that $f$ is non-decreasing, it's immediate. If $f$ isn't non-decreasing, it can be wrong.

Comment: I edited my last comment to make it more precise in context of integration.

Comment: I need this in order to fully understand a proof of improper definite integral test.

Comment: Since $f \geqslant 0$, $F$ is non-decreasing, so for any $a \leqslant x \leqslant y < \infty$, we have $$F(x) \leqslant F(y) \xrightarrow{y\to\infty} M.$$

Comment: I could write $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} F(x) - F(b) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \int^x_b f(s) ds \ge 0 = M - F(b) \ \ \forall b \in \mathbb R$$ ? Also $f(s) \ge 0$.

Comment: Yes, you could write it so.